# How do I resize a System.Windows.Forms.ToolBar?

Tags: c#, .net, toolbar

I've not bothered with panels, docking, or anchors.  I've simply thrown together a ToolBar control (not ToolStrip) and seem unable to size it.

```
System.Windows.Forms.ToolBar tb = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolBar();

// Reports 292x28 (approx) if I check width and height
// Basically the width of the form and I assume a default height
tb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(195, 48);


// Reports 48x48, but does not actually create buttons of that size
// (It reports 48x48 because I'm retrieving 48x48 icons from a ResourceManager (resx))
tb.ButtonSize = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 48); //
```

The closest thing I found to making my ToolBar taller was:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/241614-changing-height-toolbar-button

Although it's rather dated.  And I didn't understand it.  ToolBarButtons don't have Height, Width, or Size properties.

I'm using SharpDevelop, coding completely by hand on Vista, with all the .NET frameworks.

EDIT:

Here is the EXACT code that I am currently using.

```
#region ImageList/Toolbar
ImageList toolbarImages = new ImageList();
Image wizardToolbarImage = (Bitmap) rm.GetObject("wizard");
Image optionsToolbarImage = (Bitmap) rm.GetObject("configure");
toolbarImages.Images.Add(wizardToolbarImage);
toolbarImages.Images.Add(optionsToolbarImage);      

ToolBar toolbarMain = new ToolBar();
toolbarMain.Size = new Size(195, 25); // no effect
ToolBarButton wizardToolbarButton = new ToolBarButton();
ToolBarButton optionsToolbarButton = new ToolBarButton();
wizardToolbarButton.ImageIndex = 0;
wizardToolbarButton.ToolTipText = "Wizard!";
optionsToolbarButton.ImageIndex = 1;
optionsToolbarButton.ToolTipText = "Options!";
toolbarMain.Buttons.Add(wizardToolbarButton);   
toolbarMain.Buttons.Add(optionsToolbarButton);

toolbarMain.Appearance = ToolBarAppearance.Normal;
toolbarMain.ButtonSize = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 48); // no effect
toolbarMain.ImageList = toolbarImages;
toolbarMain.ButtonClick += new ToolBarButtonClickEventHandler(toolbarMain_Click);

Controls.Add(toolbarMain);
#endregion
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give me some example code for comparison then?  As is, mine are MUCH smaller than 48x48.  I'll add some more of the code to the original to illustrate all of what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

In just about every winforms application I've written, regardless of language or framework, the toolbar could only be made taller by using larger icons.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the toolstrip inside a Panel and set the Dock property of the tool strip to Fill.  And then you can size the Panel to whatever size you need.

Comment: A `System.Windows.Forms.ToolBar` is **not** the same thing as a `System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip`. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: @Cody Gray. You're right, my bad.  The solution I suggested will not work for a System.Windows.Forms.ToolBar.